# Navigation Launcher not working in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am getting an error while integrating launcher navigation in android in eclipse, Please have a look in it. It would help me a lot.

**Plugin Used:** cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator

**Link of plugin:**  https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator

**Library Added in libs folder:**  v 3.6.0 JAR(okhttp3 library)

**Link of Library:** http://square.github.io/okhttp/

**Error:**

03-27 12:15:08.927: W/System.err(32008): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/OkHttpClient
03-27 12:15:08.937: W/System.err(32008):    at uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.LaunchNavigator.(LaunchNavigator.java:113)
03-27 12:15:08.937: W/System.err(32008):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-27 12:15:08.937: W/System.err(32008):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
03-27 12:15:08.937: W/System.err(32008):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.instantiatePlugin(PluginManager.java:492)
03-27 12:15:08.937: W/System.err(32008):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.getPlugin(PluginManager.java:169)
03-27 12:15:08.937: W/System.err(32008):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:122)
03-27 12:15:08.937: W/System.err(32008):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
03-27 12:15:08.937: W/System.err(32008):    at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
03-27 12:15:08.937: W/System.err(32008):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
03-27 12:15:08.937: W/System.err(32008):    at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:24)
03-27 12:15:08.937: W/System.err(32008):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-27 12:15:08.937: W/System.err(32008):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-27 12:15:08.937: W/System.err(32008):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Thanks,
Kanishka

Comment: Why do you need to develop your application with PhoneGap and eclipse?

Comment: Don't worry, the issue is resolved.